# Is this 3D graphics computation question from Photo-SE on topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, migration

Over at Photo-SE, we have a question from a new user that seems like it would be on-topic here:

[Calculating the new coordinate of a point in the camera field of view after rotating the camera around the z -axis](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/114499/calculating-the-new-coordinate-of-a-point-in-the-camera-field-of-view-after-rota)

I just wanted to check with your Meta before I vote to migrate the question over here.

Comment: For those of you who contribute both to CG-SE and [gamedev.se]. which site would be better for the linked question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've contributed on both, but have been far more active on GDSE & than on CGSE.

I think the question could work in either place. GDSE gets more traffic, however I suspect that CGSE has more technical expertise relevant to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got a similar [response at GDSE](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2832/135655), but it sounds like it's a better fit here. I'm going to ask to have it migrated here.